# Specific results relating the option of drop list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this drop down list:

```
<select name="asfalia" id="asfalia" class="validate['required'] arrow" style="height:24px;">
    <option id="none" selected="selected" value="">Επιλέξτε</option>
    <option id="car" value="Αυτοκινήτου">Αυτοκινήτου</option>
    <option id="moto" value="Μηχανής">Μηχανής</option>
    <option id="house" value="Σπιτιού">Σπιτιού</option>
    <option id="bussines" value="Επιχείρησης">Επιχείρησης</option>
    <option id="boat" value="Σκάφους">Σκάφους</option>
    <option id="life" value="Ζωής">Ζωής</option>
    <option id="health" value="Υγείας">Υγείας</option>
</select>
```

What I want is when someone choose an option then to display a specific content relating to the option.

e.g

for car option:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            Car Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

e.g2

for moto option:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            Moto Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The amount of divs means that there is multiple code inside, I did it like that just in hurry.

Comment: So you want to make an ajax request and populate that div with the response?

Comment: switch case on `$_GET['asfalia']` if the select is in a form that is submitted

Comment: @Steve and how can I insert html code for specific option?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a page with one select field, and many pre-generated divs which you want to show only when the specific option is selected.

If that is the case, then here is what you're looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#asfalia').on('change', function() {
    var selectedID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    $("[id^=option-]").hide();
    if (selectedID != "") {
      $("#option-" + selectedID).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#container-options div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="asfalia" id="asfalia" class="validate['required'] arrow" style="height:24px;">
  <option id="none" selected="selected" value="">Επιλέξτε</option>
  <option id="car" value="Αυτοκινήτου">Αυτοκινήτου</option>
  <option id="moto" value="Μηχανής">Μηχανής</option>
</select>
<div>
  <div>
    <div id="container-options">
      <div id="option-car">
        Some content when car is selected
      </div>
      <div id="option-moto">
        Some content when moto is selected
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What you have to do is to add some valuable content for each div, it doesn't matter that you have many parent divs, as long as the identifier is unique.

I've included just the first two options, but I think you'll get the idea.

Comment: It looks interesting. I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: Let me give you an example. If your code was in my website as an interest form with fields also. I would like to send an email back to a person who filled the form. I have a template (for email) for every section of the form (cars, motos etc) in one template and I want relating to this person's option to send back an email and show him the fields that he filled in the specific section (e.g cars).

Comment: So, I don't want to display whole template to email but only the section that he filled. Moreover, the only thing that I can take from the webpage is the value of option (e.g value="option1") on that way "{asfalia}" (it takes dynamically the value of options in joomla that is selected)

Comment: Well, you can just apply some CSS at the begining of the email to only show the relevant part (selected option), or do X templates (1 for each option) and just send out the correct one.